# Issue on assigning function to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following demo. Why am I not able to get the result of a function assigned to a variable?

```js
var cartssku = function() {
  $(".cart").each(function() {
    skus = [];
    skus.push($(this).data('sku'));
    return skus.join();
  });
};

console.log(cartssku);
```

```css
.cart {
  background: gold;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-01"> Cart SKU I</div>
<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-02"> Cart SKU II</div>
<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-03"> Cart SKU III</div>
```

Comment: You should call the function ```cartssku()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. if your function is returning something, you have to call it like a function: yourfunction();
2. the function inside the function is returning something, not the function that you're calling is returning something.
   try this:

```js
var cartssku = function() {
  var skus = [];

  $(".cart").each(function() {
    skus.push($(".cart").data('sku'));
  });
  return skus.join()

};

console.log(cartssku());
```

```css
.cart {
  background: gold;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-01"> Cart SKU I</div>
<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-02"> Cart SKU II</div>
<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-03"> Cart SKU III</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the first and last statements from inside the `.each()` method; initializing belongs before the `.each()` method and `return`  belongs after as shown below. Then call the function by appending `()` as shown:

```js
var cartssku = function() {
  var skus = [];
  $(".cart").each(function() {
    skus.push($(this).data('sku'));
  });
  return skus.join();
};

console.log( cartssku() );
```

```css
.cart {
  background: gold;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-01"> Cart SKU I</div>
<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-02"> Cart SKU II</div>
<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-03"> Cart SKU III</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use the jQuery `.map()` method as in the demo below:

```js
var cartssku = function() {
    return $(".cart").map(function() {
        return $(this).data('sku');
    })
    .get().join();
};

console.log( cartssku() );
```

```css
.cart {
  background: gold;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-01"> Cart SKU I</div>
<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-02"> Cart SKU II</div>
<div class="cart" data-sku="mt-03"> Cart SKU III</div>
```